# Codux installation React app, Cannot find compiled file

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

I'm trying [Codux](https://www.codux.com/) and when I create an empty project or one from a template, it compiles successfully on the system disk but not on the external disk.
When installing React app with Codux on external disk I got error:

```
Cannot find compiled file /home/.../testApp/src/_codux/boards/app/app.board.tsx
```

I suspect a file permission problem but I see that some files are created in the destination folder, maybe one of the build commands needs more permission.
But this doesn't happen when I install a React application from VSCode on that disk.

I tried to install it on **Documents** successfully then move files on my external disk but still got same error.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and Codux V.15.19.0.